# How to dynamically add a hyperlink (BookmarkablePageLink) to DefaultDataTable that is rendered as an anchor

Tags: apache, anchor, wicket

I have a DefaultDataTable that gets its columns programmatically.

The markup is simple:

```
        <table wicket:id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="90%" />
```

All of the columns are dynamically generated from a passed in LinkedHashMap of labels and attributes:

```
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : entrySet) {
        final String label = entry.getKey();
        final String attribute = entry.getValue();
        columns.add(new PsPropertyColumn(label, attribute) {

            @Override
            public void populateItem(Item cellItem, String componentId, IModel model)
            {
                final Object modelObject = model.getObject();
                final Object value = PropertyResolver.getValue(attribute, modelObject);
                // Add an edit link
                BookmarkablePageLink link = new ...;
                ...
                cellItem.add(link);
            }
        }
    }

    DefaultDataTable table = new DefaultDataTable("dataTable", columns, dataProvider, MAX_ROWS) {
        ...
    }
    add(table);
```

As many posts have mentioned, this is rendered as a cell with an onclick handler rather than an anchor (<a href="..." />) tag.  I want the anchor tag for a couple of reasons, one if which is that I want to add my own onclick handler without having an existing onclick handler in the way.

I have seen the generally accepted solution that says to put an anchor tag inside a panel in the HTML markup, and to add the link inside of a Panel subclass.  However, that doesn't give the entire html markup (inside the table), and I think the column () tags must be a part of this markup, which I don't think works with my strategy of dynamically generating the columns (I don't even know or care how many will be asked for).  Is there a way to render my dynamically generated columns as anchor tags without specifying in the markup how many there?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: "I think the column () tags must be a part of this markup"

No, they must not be part of the panel's markup. The panel only needs to contain markup for whatever you want to render inside the TD tags. DefaultDataTable itself is a panel that renders the whole tr/td hierarchy based on the configured dynamic column list.

Answer (score 0):

I have used nested ListView components to be able to have more control over the layout as below:

html:

```
<table wicket:id="listViewContainer">
    <tr>
        <th wicket:id="columnHeaderListView">
            <span wicket:id="columnHeaderLabel">Header Label</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr wicket:id="rowListView">
        <td wicket:id="rowColumnListView">
            <a href="#" wicket:id="link">
                <span wicket:id="linkLabel">Link Label</span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Java:

```
WebMarkupContainer listViewContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("listViewContainer");
listViewContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
add(listViewContainer);

ListView columnHeaderListView = new ListView("columnHeaderListView", columnHeaderList) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem listItem) {
        ColumnHeader ch = (ColumnHeader) listItem.getModelObject();
        listItem.add(new Label("columnHeaderLabel", new Model(ch.getLabel())));
    }
};
listViewContainer.add(columnHeaderListView);

ListView rowListView = new ListView("rowListView", rowList) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem listItem) {
        Row row = (Row) listItem.getModelObject();
        listItem.add(new ListView("rowColumnListView", getRowColumnList(row)){
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem li) {
                RowColumn rowColumn = (RowColumn) li.getModelObject();
                Link link = new BookmarkablePageLink("link",...
                li.add(link);
                link.add(new Label("linkLabel", new Model(rowColumn.getLabel())));
            }
        });
    }
}
listViewContainer.add(rowListView);
```

Comment: Thank you, but aren't you requiring that I specify the number of columns in the markup?  I am currently building all of my columns (BookmarkablePageLinks) on the fly.  Is there a way to do what you do without pre-defining each column in the html?

Comment: I have edited my answer to have BookmarkablePageLinks for every column.  The number of columns is determined by the size of the list passed to the ListView.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  We have spent the last few days upgrading to Wicket 6.8 and am having the same problem.  Whether I use OnesAndZeros markup (tr,td, span tags) or only what I want to render inside the TD tags (only an anchor tag within the table tag), I get the same error:


Last cause: Close tag not found for tag: <table wicket:id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="90%">. For  Components only raw markup is allow in between the tags but not other Wicket Component. Component: [DefaultDataTable [Component id = dataTable]]

Comment: By the way, the links all render dynamically and do work.  The only problem is they are rendered as div tags with onclick handlers and I am looking for anchor tags.